# cannot import name 'get_running_loop' from 'asyncio'

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

There is a simple script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
    
wb = xw.Book('Excel_Python-1.xlsx') 
data_excel = wb.sheets['Данные'] 
data_pd = data_excel.range('A1:C4').options(pd.DataFrame, header = 1, index = False).value 
print(data_pd)
```

At startup error:
cannot import name 'get_running_loop' from 'asyncio'

Checked that the 'get_running_loop' method is in the events.py module from 'asyncio'.
What could be the problem?

```
"C:\Program Files\Python_370\python.exe" O:/___Python/__Examples/Excel/excel-1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:/___Python/__Examples/Excel/excel-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .udfs import xlfunc as func, xlsub as sub, xlret as ret, xlarg as arg, get_udf_module, import_udfs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\site-packages\xlwings\udfs.py", line 4, in <module>
    from asyncio import get_running_loop
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_running_loop' from 'asyncio' (C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\asyncio\__init__.py)
```

I ran the script interactively. Here's the result:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.7.0a1 (v3.7.0a1:8f51bb4, Sep 19 2017, 19:32:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
... import xlwings as xw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .udfs import xlfunc as func, xlsub as sub, xlret as ret, xlarg as arg, get_udf_module, import_udfs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\site-packages\xlwings\udfs.py", line 4, in <module>
    from asyncio import get_running_loop
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_running_loop' from 'asyncio' (C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\asyncio\__init__.py)
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python_370\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "C:\Program Files\Python_370\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

>>>
>>> wb = xw.Book('Excel_Python-1.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xw' is not defined
>>> data_excel = wb.sheets['Данные']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'wb' is not defined
>>> data_pd = data_excel.range('A1:C4').options(
...     pd.DataFrame, header = 1, index = False).value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'data_excel' is not defined
>>> print(data_pd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'data_pd' is not defined
```

But what conclusions to draw from this - I do not know

Comment: Show the entire stack trace, not just the last line. The error message alone does not tell us where the problem is.

Comment: can you check with python version > 3.7 and see if it works? `from asyncio import get_running_loop` works for me using python 3.8

Comment: I have exactly Python 3.7

Comment: `get_running_loop` was introduced with Python 3.7. Try to import it on an interactive prompt and see if you get the same error `from asyncio import get_running_loop`.

Comment: I launched the same program on another computer Win 8.1, Python 3.9.1. When run from command line and PyCharm everything is fine, when run from Wing there are errors. Maybe it makes sense to upgrade Python? What do you think?

Comment: Moved to python 3.8. This error does not exist, but there are other problems. How can I close this topic?